# Como puedo acceder a elementos de un HTML desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django

tengo varios cuadros de dialogo definidos en mi arcvhivo HTML

```
<div id="content-top-left-1">

            <div id="button"><a href="#VigaModal">Agregar Viga</a></div>

            <div id="VigaModal" class="modalmask"></div>
            <div class="modalbox movedown" id="uno">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" id="close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>AGREGAR VIGA</h2>
                <p>Por favor complete todos los campos sin unidades.</p>
                <p>
                    Longitud de la viga:
                    <input type="number" min="1" id="txtLongViga" name="txtLongViga">
                </p>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button class="btn-opc-2" id="btnViga" name="btnViga">AGREGAR</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="button"><a href="#modalApoyo">Agregar Apoyo</a></div>

            <div id="modalApoyo" class="modalmask"></div>
            <div class="modalbox movedown" id="dos">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <h2>AGREGAR APOYO</h2>
                <p>Por favor complete todos los campos sin unidades.</p>
                <div id="modalCP-dialog">
                    <div id="modalCP-dialog-1">
                        <p>
                            Tipo de apoyo:
                            <select>
                                {% for i in Apoyos %}
                                <option value={{ i.id }}>{{ i.apoyo }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modalCP-dialog-2">
                        <p>
                            Ubicación [m]:
                            <input type="number" min="1">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn-opc-2">AGREGAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>           

        </div>
```

y necesito acceder al `id` de  la clase `"modalbox movedown"` desde mi archivo .js lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma y no he podido.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#content-top-left-1").on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        let idSeleccionado = $(this).attr("href")
        let idClassSeleccionado = $(this).attr("id")
        // let idClassSeleccionado = $("#modalbox movedown").attr("id")
        console.log("Hola----", idSeleccionado)
        console.log("Hola****", this)
        console.log("Hola****", idClassSeleccionado)


        // $('.modalmask').show()
        $("#dos").show()
        // $("#VigaModal").show()
        $(idSeleccionado).show()
    });
});
```

Por favor, necesito ayuda...

Comment: puedes hacer que se ejecute? es que puede que asi vea mejor tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te refieres a la línea que tienes comentada

```
// let idClassSeleccionado = $("#modalbox movedown").attr("id")
```

Si es eso, como estás accediendo a clases no has de usar la almohadilla # sino el punto, de la siguiente manera

```
let idClassSeleccionado = $(".modalbox.movedown").attr("id")
```

Pero ten en cuenta que hay más de una coincidencia